# Entity Framework Field Is Required (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been having this issue and have been trying to figure out for the past few days, I set up a second test project as my first project is too big to try and nail this down. I'm still fairly new to mvvm so I'm still learning. Whenever I try to save a field using Entity it starts complaining the FirstName field is required, I sort of nailed down the issue to being apart of something with the button because whenever I move the button into the same UserControl as the textbox it will save. The TabControl in the MainWindow has a UserControl for each tab and each one has their own respective ViewModel and then the TabControl itself has a ViewModel.

**MainWindow**
Just contains the button and the tab control

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:TabControlViewModel x:Key="tab"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource tab}">
        <TabControl Margin="10"
                    Width="500"
                    Height="500">
            <TabItem Header="Test Tab 1">
                <custom:TabOneUserControl/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Test Tab 2">
                <custom:TabTwoUserControl/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

        <Button Content="Save"
                Width="120"
                Height="50" 
                Margin="1114,604,41,38.5"
                Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
```

**TabOneUserControl**
Contains a textbox and label

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:TabOneUserControlViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Content="First Name"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Width="250"
                     Height="50"
                     Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**TabTwoUserControl**
Contains a textbox and label

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:TabTwoUserControlViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Content="Last Name"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Width="250"
                     Height="50"
                     Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**TabControlViewModel**
For the tab control

```
public class TabControlViewModel
    {
        public SaveCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
        private TabOneUserControlViewModel tabOneUserControl;
        private TabTwoUserControlViewModel tabTwoUserControl;

        public TabControlViewModel()
        {
            tabOneUserControl = new TabOneUserControlViewModel();
            tabTwoUserControl = new TabTwoUserControlViewModel();
            SaveCommand = new SaveCommand(this);
        }

        public void SaveInformation()
        {
            using (TestDbEntities test = new TestDbEntities())
            {
                test.FNs.Add(new FN
                {
                    FirstName = tabOneUserControl.FirstName
                });

                test.LNs.Add(new LN
                {
                    LastName = tabTwoUserControl.LastName
                });

                try
                {
                    test.SaveChanges();
                    Debug.Print("SAVED CHANGES!");
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation(
                                  "Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                                  validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                                  validationError.PropertyName,
                                  validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**TabOneUserControlViewModel**
For the first tab user control

```
public class TabOneUserControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string firstName;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
        public TabOneUserControlViewModel()
        {

        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

**TabTwoUserControlViewModel**
For the second tab user control

```
public class TabTwoUserControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string lastName;

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public TabTwoUserControlViewModel()
        {

        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have 3 different view models ? And each of them contains a property ? `StaticResource` as VM creates a new view model instance, so those instances are not the same as the ones you create in your `TabControlViewModel`

Comment: I would for sure only create `TabControlViewModel` and keep both First and Last names in that one. I would also get rid of the StaticResouce vm's in TabControl 1 and 2

Comment: In general, UserControls should never have their own, private view models. They should instead bind to the properties of the view model object in the DataContext that is inherited from their parent element.

Comment: @Clemens In general any view/control should never have their own, private ViewModel **instance**.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Yes I have 3 different view models with different properties. In my main project I have too many properties to just place in a single class so I opted to create view models for each tab in my main project and store them in each one respectively. So by using StaticResource I'm creating a new instance of each? What would be the proper way to solve this. I'm still fairly new to mvvm.

Comment: @Clemens I have around 200 properties in my main project. So moving these all into the base TabControlViewModel and deleting the UserControls would be better?

Comment: @DavidHoward Anything that you put in View.Resource will create a new instance.

Comment: @DavidHoward You may still have multiple view models. They should however not be instantiated in the XAML or code of a control. You might have a "main view model" which holds the others as properties.

Comment: You can still create those seperate view models in the main VM, and change it from private to public. You binding instead would look like `<TextBox Text="{Binding tabTwoUserControl.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: Or even better `<Grid DataContext="{Binding tabTwoUserControl}" >`

Comment: If you get an EntityFramework Message, your problem is in FN.Firstname, Hope you realize that.  Sure it comes from your other model, but then it's not a EF related problem.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Thanks so much, that solved it for me, so it was because I was using a StaticResource is why this issue happened. Changed it like your suggestion and it worked perfectly. Also thanks to everyone else who commented and helped. You're awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone in the comments for your suggestions, Nawed's comment nailed it perfectly for what I was doing wrong. Here is the final code changes I made:

**TabControlViewModel**
Removed the fields and made them into properties

```
public class TabControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public SaveCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

        public TabOneUserControlViewModel TabOneUserControl { get; set; }

        public TabTwoUserControlViewModel TabTwoUserControl { get; set; }

        public TabControlViewModel()
        {
            TabOneUserControl = new TabOneUserControlViewModel();
            TabTwoUserControl = new TabTwoUserControlViewModel();
            SaveCommand = new SaveCommand(this);
        }

        public void SaveInformation()
        {
            using (TestDbEntities test = new TestDbEntities())
            {
                test.FNs.Add(new FN
                {
                    FirstName = TabOneUserControl.FirstName
                });

                test.LNs.Add(new LN
                {
                    LastName = TabTwoUserControl.LastName
                });

                try
                {
                    test.SaveChanges();
                    Debug.Print("SAVED CHANGES!");
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation(
                                  "Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                                  validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                                  validationError.PropertyName,
                                  validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

**TabOneUserControl**
Removed the static resource from the grid and replaced it with a regular binding and then changed the binding in the Text element, this was the same thing I did in the second user control so I will negate posting the second UserControl:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding TabOneUserControl}">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Content="First Name"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Width="250"
                     Height="50"
                     Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```